# Django writing generic update view restricted to certain user

Tags: python, django

I am building a small blog using django.I want to build a function that allow post author to delete and update their own posts.
Then I find django has LoginMixin for generic view,but it only block those who don't login.

My article Model is like below

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    context = models.TextField()

    genre_choice = (('O','Others'),('P','Programming'),('L','Learning'),('E','Entertainment'))

    genre = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=genre_choice,default='O')
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title,self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("article-detail",args=str(self.id))
```

This is the generic article detail view.

```
class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Article
```

I firstly want to add something like this in the detail template:

```
{% if article.author == user.username%}
 <!-- Some a tag that directs to the update view -->
{% endif %}
```

Then I realize that this just hides the a tag ,it can't stop other users to touch the update url simply change the url.

Is there anyway in django can restricted the update and delete permissions to the original user by simply using generic view?Even if they directly enter the update url,they will be rejected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override `get_queryset` in your `UpdateView`, so that the user can only access items that they authored. Use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin) to ensure that only logged-in users can access the view.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class UpdateArticle(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(UpdateArticle, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```

In the template, I would compare the `author_id` with the user's primary key to decide whether to show the link or not.

```
{% if article.author_id == user.pk %}
```

Comment: Now users will get a 404 error when they try to touch update url which they are not authors.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Since you only want to show the update link to the author, I assumed that would be ok. This is a really typical approach in Django. If you want to show a permission denied message instead of 404, then you'll need to try a different approach, and the code will probably be more complicated.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks for the tip! Can you point to an example on how to set up an error redirect page?

Comment: @ycode you could try the approach in Sayyor Y’s answer

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create your own mixin/decorator to check if the logged user is the author, if not then reload/show a message etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a safer way now would be to use built-in mixin `UserPassesTestMixin`. In particular, you can inherit it in your class and change its `test_func()` to check for the author. Don't forget to also inherit `LoginRequiredMixin` to make sure the user is logged in:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin

class UpdateArticle(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Article

    def test_func(self):
        thisArticle = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == thisArticle.author:
            return True
        return False
```

If a user who is not the author attempts to update the article, '403 Forbidden' Error is returned which is just what you want in such a situation.